# Simplify this matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

Consider the (nonsymmetric) positive-definite triadiagonal matrix $P$ of diagonal $2$ and sub-diagonal $-1$, except for the last row which is $[0\  \dots\  0 \ 1]$ and define

$$ M_n=\begin{bmatrix} 0_n & I_n \\ -P & 0_n \end{bmatrix}.$$

For example, for $n=3$, 
$$M_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0
&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&1\\ -2&1&0&0&0&0
\\ 1&-2&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&-1&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Can I simplify $\exp(tM_n)$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$, *i.e.* find an appropriate basis which would make the expression simpler?

The characteristic polynomial of $M_3$ is $(1 + X^2)^2 (3 + X^2)$, for $M_4$ it is $(1 + X^2) (2 + X^2) (2 + 4 X^2 + X^4)$... it's does not seem simple.

$P$ has square root $P^{1/2}$ and $M_n$ can be made skew-symmetric:

$$\begin{bmatrix} P^{1/2} & 0_n \\ 0_n & I_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0_n & I_n \\ -P & 0_n \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} P^{1/2} & 0_n \\ 0_n & I_n \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & P^{1/2} \\ -P^{1/2} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and the exponential of a skew-symmetric matrix is orthogonal (because if $M=-M^\top$, then $M$ and $M^\top$ commute so $\exp(M+M^\top)=I=\exp(M)\exp(M^\top)$) but that's all what I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong. Since $P$ is not symmetric, the matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&P^{1/2}\\-P^{1/2}&0\end{pmatrix}$ is not skew-symmetric.

Let $p_n(x)=\det(xI_n-P_n)$ and $q_n(x)=\det(xI_{2n}-M_n)=\det(x^2I_n+P_n)$. Thus, up to a signum, $q_n(x)=p_n(-x^2)$. Now, the $n$ eigenvalues of $P_n$ are $\{1\}\cup \{2+2\cos(\dfrac{k\pi}{n}),k=1,\cdots,n-1\}$.

Clearly, the eigenvalues of $P$ are $>0$ and, consequently, we can define $P^{1/2}$ as a matrix that has only $>0$ eigenvalues. Yet, a priori, $e^B$ is not orthogonal.

Finally $e^{tM}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(tP^{1/2})&\sin(tP^{1/2})P^{-1/2}\\-\sin(tP^{1/2})P^{1/2}&\cos(tP^{1/2})\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: OK, I got it, you use the definition of exponential, then the form of $B^{2p}$ and $B^{2p+1}$ and the Taylor expansions of $\sin$ and $\cos$. I still have two questions: i) why do you care that $P^{1/2}$ has $>0$ eigenvalues? ii) How did you find the eigenvalues of $P_n$?! I managed to show that $P_n$ is (nonsymmetric) positive definite, because $x^\top P_n x = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (x_i-x_{i-1})^2 + (x_n-x_{n-1})$ (with $x_0=0$) which is $0$ iff all $x_i=0$. That's enough to show that the eigenvalues of $P$ are $>0$ (I think) but I am curious.

Comment: for i). $x^TP_nx>0$ implies only that, for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $P_n$, $Re(\lambda )>0$. For ii) Let $Q_n$ be the triadiagonal matrix of diagonal $2$ and lower-upper diagonal $−1$. Then $spectrum(P_n)=\{1\}\cup spectrum(Q_{n-1})$ and $spectrum(Q_n)$ is well-known (cf. a book about discretization of diff. equ.)

Comment: OK; additional steps if ever someone is interested: eigenvalues of $Q_n$ are given by http://mathoverflow.net/a/188489/54797 and the equality of spectrum is obvious when developping w.r.t to the last row of $P_n$.

Comment: @ anderstood , thanks for the bounty.